# Determine $f^{-1}$ such that $f$ is defined from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(f(x))=4x-9$

Tags: functions

It is easy to see that $f$ is bijective so i don't need to prove it .

For the question, here is what I did :

we know that $$f(f^{-1}(x))=x$$
so by replacing $x$ with $f^{-1}(x)$ we will  see that $$f(x)=4f^{-1}(x)-9$$
$$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{f(x)+9}{4}$$
However i need to find $f^{-1}$ in function of $x$

Comment: $f(x)=2x-3$ does it.

Comment: Did you want just a single solution? Or did you want all possible solutions?

Comment: $f(x)=9-2x$ does it too.

Comment: i need all the solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no unique solution to this problem. For starters, we have these two solutions:

$$f(x)=2x-3$$
$$f(x)=9-2x$$

But now we have the solution
$$
  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
2x-3  & \text{if $x\in\mathbb Q$} \\
9-2x & \text{if $x\notin \mathbb Q$}
\end{cases}
$$

because $x\in\mathbb Q \iff 2x-3\in\mathbb Q$ and $x\in\mathbb Q \iff 9-2x\in\mathbb Q$.

Continuing in this vein, let $S$ be any set such that $x\in S \iff 2x-3\in S$ and $x\in S \iff 9-2x\in S$. Then we have the solution
$$
  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
2x-3  & \text{if $x\in S$} \\
9-2x & \text{if $x\notin S$}
\end{cases}
$$

There are many such sets $S$ (the algebraic numbers, for instance). I don't know whether all solutions are of this form.